# Query filter in composer rest server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, strongloop, hyperledger-composer, loopback

I'm having problems with queries in composer rest server.

I'm building a filter like this:

```
{
    "where": {
        "and": [
        {
            "origin": "web"
        },
        {
            "affiliate": "resource:org.acme.affiliates.Affiliate#2"
        },
        {
            "createdAt": {
            "gte": "2018-01-01"
            }
        },
        {
            "createdAt": {
            "lte": "2018-06-07"
            }
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

request:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:3000/api/User?filter=%7B%22where%22%3A%7B%22and%22%3A%5B%7B%22origin%22%3A%22web%22%7D%2C%7B%22affiliate%22%3A%22resource%3Aorg.acme.affiliates.Affiliate%232%22%7D%2C%7B%22createdAt%22%3A%7B%22gte%22%3A%222018-01-01%22%2C%22lte%22%3A%222018-06-07%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D'
```

response:

```
[
    {
        "$class": "org.acme.affiliates.User",
        "affiliate": "resource:org.acme.affiliates.Affiliate#2",
        "userId": "14",
        "email": "diego@duncan.com",
        "firstName": "diego",
        "lastName": "duncan",
        "createdAt": "2018-04-20T20:48:08.151Z",
        "origin": "web"
    },
    {
        "$class": "org.acme.affiliates.User",
        "affiliate": "resource:org.acme.affiliates.Affiliate#1",
        "userId": "15",
        "email": "diego@algo.com",
        "firstName": "diego",
        "lastName": "algo",
        "createdAt": "2018-04-20T20:53:40.720Z",
        "origin": "web"
    }
]
```

As you see, filters are not working because Affiliate#1 appears.
I tested without createdAt filters and work perfectly, then i tested without affiliate and work good too. I tested with createdAt with range instead gte and lte with the same wrong result.

hlfv1

composer rest server v0.16.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer my own question:

I was using hlfv1 and composer 0.16.6

After update to hlfv11 and composer 0.19.8 the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

its a loopback filter issue, most likely to do with the date range comparison. (the other comparisons are fine as you wrote).

The suggestion here -> https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/issues/176 would suggest that you need to use the `between` operator instead  for DateTimes. eg

```
{"where":{"createdAt":{"between": ['2018-01-05 10:00', '2018-05-10 10:00']}}}
```

Comment: I already tested with **between** and doesn't work, 

`{"where":{"and":[{"affiliate":"resource:org.acme.affiliates.Affiliate#2"},{"createdAt":{"between":["2018-01-06","2018-04-20"]}},{"origin":"web"}]}}`

thanks for you answer.